# Is the limit of positive weakly convergence sequence nonnegative?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\{u_n\}$ be a sequence of functions in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N), p>1$, $u_n>0$ for all $n$, such that $u_n\rightharpoonup u$. Then $u\ge 0$. Is that true? If not, any counterexample? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set
$$\{u \in W^{1,p} \;|\; u \ge 0 \; \text{a.e.}\}$$
is closed and convex, thus weakly closed.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that also my answer only yields $u \ge 0$ a.e. However, you cannot expect much more since the elements in $W^{1,p}$ are equivalence classes of functions.

Comment: I get it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true. Let $\phi\in C_c^\infty$ with $\phi\ge0$. Then
$$
0\le \int \phi u_m  \to \int \phi u.
$$
So, $ \int \phi u\ge0$ for all smooth and non-negative $\phi$. Hence $u\ge0$ a.e.

Comment: By $\int \phi u\ge 0$, we only get $u\ge 0$ a.e.  But thank you all the same.